# Multithreading in Qt

Tags: c++, openssl, qt5

I'm writing a small GUI to encrypt and decrypt files using openSSL command line interface.
I need a progress bar to show the encryption progress when encrypting/decrypting large files.
Since I use the cli interface there is no intermediate return value or other helping me with this, so the only way I found to know the progress is to write a multi-threaded program in which the first thread calls openSSL in a terminal

e.g.

`system("openssl aes-256-cbc -in clear_text_file -out encrypted_file")`

while the second thread reads every second the file size of the output file and, comparing it with the original file size computes the progress bar value. The problem here is that there is no thread synchronization, so when the pc is busy the second thread is often not executed every second, but every five or six or worse not executed at all until the end of the first thread and the result is that the progress bar remains always stuck to zero until the end of the encryption process. I also tried to set the priority of the first thread to low but I noticed no change (I'm using Qt5.1 on Linux, and I read somewhere that thread priority in Linux is not supported, so that might be the reason).

If anyone here could suggest me some other (preferably better) way to achive the same result I would be very grateful..

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to use the openSSL (or equivalent) library directly to get more granular progress updates instead of through invoking a seperate process and polling filesize (which will only be updated based on how often the file is flushed)

Comment: But I think the problem remains the same because, even using the C API of OpenSSL, (which seems to have a very poor documentation) after setting up the algorithm and the key, there is a function which does all the encryption job and terminates when finished, so there is no intermediate stop to update the progress bar..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use

```
proc = new QProcess();
proc.start("openssl aes-256-cbc -in clear_text_file -out encrypted_file");
connect(proc,SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()),this,SLOT(readStdout()));
```

I think the openssl would have processing infromation output to the standerOutput,You can use
readyReadStandardOutput() to tigger readStdout() defined by yourself to get the processing infromation.

Comment: as far as i know (I just finished reading "man openssl") there is no such thing (intermediate output information on stdout) in openssl.

Comment: You can add a listener on the finished signal of the openssl process.

Comment: Yes and that's what I already did, but the problem is that i want to check the intermediate progress of the encryption process to update the progress bar in the GUI, and with the signal at the end of the process i only obtain the "job completed" signal while i'm also interested in the "job completed at 50%" signal

Comment: can you try to redirect the openssl's output to a memory buffer?when the buffer is full,pause the process and append the buffer to a disk file.

Comment: mmm... this seems a good idea, the problem for me is that I don't know how to pause a process.. Now I will google it..

Comment: Ok, it seems I can easily pause the process with QThread::wait(), but I need a signal when the buffer is full, and this signal must be emitted not by the thread encrypting the file, but by another thread that has to check periodically the size of the data contained in the buffer, which is the same thing (correct me if I'm wrong) as reading periodically the filesize of the output file on the disk..